# Using jqGrid getChangedCells, and then marking the changes as not dirty

Tags: jquery, jqgrid

I'm using jqGrid with the getChangedCells('all') to get an array of the rows in the grid which has been changed. I send the rows to the server to save them. This works fine.

The problem is, I can't find a way to un-mark the rows as dirty. Like for example theGrid.setClean() or something similar, which to call when the server returns a success for the save-call.

Anyone knows how that could be acomplished?

**EDIT - solution found:**

By adding the following code, the problem is solved. I don't know if this is the best approach. It seems to work at this moment at least.

```
$(".edited").removeClass("edited");
$(".dirty-cell").removeClass("dirty-cell");
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can just remove `"edited"` class from the rows (from `<tr>`) which is saved on the server and "dirty-cell" class from cells (`<td>`). For example

```js
var $tr = $($grid.jqGrid('getInd', rowid, true));
$tr.removeClass("edited");
$tr.children("td").removeClass("dirty-cell");
```